# Get Microsoft Teams running on Ubuntu

Tags: microsoft, webco

I read this article and want to avoid the complicated procedure to get Microsoft Teams running on Ubuntu 18.04.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/TEAMS-and-LINUX-The-Future-is-Now/m-p/308382/highlight/true#M23115

Is there a simpler way?

## Update 2021:

Follow the official docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-clients#linux

Answer (score 10):

On my Ubuntu 18.04.2 I installed it via the command :

```
sudo snap install teams-for-linux
```

( I did not understand the other answers completely 
  and the linked versions are older 0.2.1. 
  my install is 0.3 )

Comment: Got 0.4.0 from snap on 16.04 today

Comment: Nice one. It's working for me.

Comment: But video call is not working and it's saying the camera is not available.

Comment: sudo snap connect teams-for-linux:camera

Comment: @RostislavStribrny thank you man

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following electron client:

https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux

You can do desktop and screen sharing and all the other basics (mentions, video and audio call, integrations, opening meeting links, etc)

This is a continuation from the ivelkov project.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit 2023

The Linux version of Microsoft Teams is no longer supported. It is recommnded to switch to PWA version, using Chrome, Chromium or Edge. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-progressive-web-app-now-available-on-linux/ba-p/3669846 for details.

### Repository install

Installing from the official [Microsoft Teams DEB repository](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/) has the advantage that Microsoft Teams **will get automatically updated** together with your other packages, as soon as Microsoft publishes a new release.

Here are four easy cut & paste installation steps to get about this:

1.Install the repository signing key:

```
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc |sudo apt-key add -
```

2.Add the `ms-teams` repository as a file to the `apt` `sources.list.d`:

```
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
```

3.Update the `apt` packages cache:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

4.Install `teams` from the newly added repository:

```
$ sudo apt install teams
```

Comment: In of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS the use of `apt-key` is deprecated. You add the key to keyrings and configure apt sources to use the key. `curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/packages-microsoft.gpg ; echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages-microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list`

Comment: I see below errors after following above steps. `E: Unable to locate package teams` Any clue ?

Comment: @Achal April 2023: **Teams on Linux is end-of-life.** See my edited answer above for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Install the debian package from the following repository!

https://github.com/sudhirnakka/teams-ubuntu-enhanced/releases

Comment: This works fine for me. With Chrome and Ubuntu 18 the application is running without any error. I can even participate to calls and see screenshares. I just can't share yet.

Comment: This works for as long as microsoft accepts it. As soon as they see more and more Linux users connecting they will lock us out.

Comment: @Rinzwind do you think so? Why should microsoft lock linux users out?

Comment: That is based on passed experiences. Microsoft has been proven to be unthrustworthy. Skype was one example.

Answer (score 3):

1. Microsoft Teams **Progressive Web App**:
   Login at teams.microsoft.com website in a PWA-friendly web browser (anything Chromium-based), wait/hope for the “install” prompt to be shown (if not you can use the tools > ‘create a shortcut’ menu option). (Source: [OMG! Linux](https://www.omglinux.com/microsoft-teams-pwa-now-available-on-linux/).)
2. **Web app** in the browser.
3. [**Unofficial** Microsoft Teams client for Linux using Electron](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux). It uses the Web App and wraps it as a standalone application using Electron, as **deb**-package, [**AppImage**](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/releases), [**snap** from the Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/teams-for-linux) and [**flatpak** from the Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.IsmaelMartinez.teams_for_linux).

**Discontinued**

1. **Flatpak** from the [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.microsoft.Teams). [The Linux version of Microsoft Teams is no longer supported. It is recommnded to switch to PWA version, using Chrome, Chromium or Edge. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-progressive-web-app-now-available-on-linux/ba-p/3669846 for details.]
2. December 2022 (although page https://aka.ms/get-teams-linux is still available and PWA is not shown):
   [Microsoft has released an official Linux app in **October 2020**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-is-now-available-on-linux/ba-p/1056267), if you prefer an app to the browser version of MS teams.
   I am not a fan of [MS Teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/free) but there are situations you have to use it. It seems the [MS-teams app repository (see other answer)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255079/30631) is not updated anymore.

You can install the official version as:

1. As [**deb** package from the official MS Teams download page](https://aka.ms/get-teams-linux). If you need more details how to install the deb package, you find it on [the Website for Students](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-microsoft-teams-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04/).
   [Delete configuration folders to reset Teams](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257905/30631):

   rm -rf ~/.config/teams
   rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft\ Teams
2. As **Snap** package from the Software App or [snapcraft.io-Page](https://snapcraft.io/teams) or in a terminal (`sudo snap install teams`).

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow below steps.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list'

sudo apt update
sudo apt install teams
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the officials docs now: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-clients#linux

Comment: I see below errors after following above steps. `E: Unable to locate package teams` Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

you can install by the following command

```
cd /tmp

wget https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/pool/main/t/teams/teams_1.2.00.32451_amd64.deb

dpkg -i teams_1.2.00.32451_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This looks dirty. Is there no way which works six months later. I guess above version won't  since it contains fixed version numbers.

Comment: @guettli the above URL for microsoft package has been removed since 28-Feb-2023 but you can still check the parent URL for this from below link and then download team's package according to your server compatibility

https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/