# Error message when opening MS Teams. "We're still developing Teams for Linux"

Tags: microsoft

The Microsoft website says that Microsoft Teams is available for Linux [Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/microsoft-teams-is-now-available-on-linux/ba-p/1056267)

I downloaded and installed Microsoft Teams Linux Deb 64-Bit from [download page here](https://teams.microsoft.com/downloads#allDevicesSection)

When I run it, and sign in I see this window:

[image]

I see this question:

[Get Microsoft Teams running on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106560/get-microsoft-teams-running-on-ubuntu)
which indicates that people are running it.
What gives?

---

```
$ apt list --installed | grep teams  
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.  
teams/now 1.3.00.5153 amd64 [installed,local]
```

---

Also, when I sign in with the same user name in Windows, all is well.

---

Ubuntu version 18.04.4.LTS

Comment: It's working fine for me in 18.04. What is the output of `apt list --installed | grep teams`?

Comment: See addendum to question

Comment: Well this is weird. I'm not sure why it isn't working in your case.

Comment: @kulfy is it possible because of "Access restricted" that you see on the title bar of the screenshot? Like maybe "limited preview" or something?

Comment: @Jags I'm not sure. Maybe MS is the only one who can answer. **Al**: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: The peeps at MS say it's a setting your enterprise admin has to tweak... see https://docs.microsoft.com/answers/questions/16181/teams-access-restricted-error.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using the apt package. I was able to get it working via the snap package.

```
sudo snap install teams-for-linux
```

Comment: This might work but fyi, this snap package isn't maintained by Microsoft itself and it was last update in Nov 2019 and still at version 1.0.0.

Comment: The snap package is an electron shell around the web client not written by microsoft.