# Reset MS Teams completely

Tags: apt, cache, microsoft, cleanup

I used Microsoft Teams (Linux) few months back with an organizational account. Now I want to use it with some other account. I'm currently in logged out state since I don't have access to the org account. Everytime I open, it takes me to the organizational page, and asks me to sign in. There is no `Use Another account` or `Sign In with another account` option. When you initially open, when it is sending requests to take us to the org page, there's a cancel option but that doesn't work. It makes the app unresponsive.

Now I've tried to uninstall many times with `apt-remove`, `from software center`, `purge`. Every time, I install, it picks up the data/cache, and tries to take me to the same org page. How can I completely reset, remove the data it is using to install with my new account.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try removing the configuration folders for MS Teams, under `~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams` and `~/.config/teams`, i.e. run something like this:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/teams
rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft\ Teams
```

Comment: Thank you! The following commands worked for me: `sudo dpkg --purge teams`, `rm -rf ~/.config/teams`, `rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft`, `rm -rf ~/.config/'Microsoft Teams - Preview'`, `rm -rf ~/.config/'Unknown Organization'` (I installed Teams via `dpkg -i`).

Comment: For me, it was `rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft\ Teams\ -\ Preview/`

Answer (score 2):

I suceeded by deleting all folders within the path

```
.var/app/com.microsoft.Teams
```

Comment: Is this flatpak?

Comment: I don't see this directory on Ubuntu 21.10 with MS Teams installed.

Comment: For me it was `~/.var/app/com.github.IsmaelMartinez.teams_for_linux` on PopOS