# Can't install Microsoft Teams on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, microsoft-teams

I need Teams on my laptop, but when I downloaded the package on the website it was missing some files necessary for installation shown in the below screenshot. I tried doing it with the commands I found on the internet, but the terminal only replied with `command not found`.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to AU. I'm not sure why your question has got such negative attention, but I hope I've helped with the answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Microsoft Teams running on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106560/get-microsoft-teams-running-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I use 22.04LTS and it works fine.

Go back to Microsoft's website and download it directly (the file is called teams_1.5.00.23861_amd64.deb).

Then go to your Downloads folder and open the download with the software manager - you may need to right-click, select 'Open with other application' and then 'Software Install'.